# SQL Server loop update in batches of 20

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have problem where I have a table with 20000+ records I need to update DateServiceStart column with a date but i don't want to set it to with a single date for all 20k records.

I want to spread the dates out over say 5 days, when you get to row 6 in the table I want to loop back and use the the starting date.

I already have the update statement just not sure how to loop through? Any help appreciated!

```
RowNum | DateServiceStart
1 | 01/01/2014
2| 02/01/2014
3| 03/01/2014
4| 04/01/2014
5| 05/01/2014
...
6|01/01/2014
7|02/01/2014
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is `ID` key field in the table (or you can change it to `ROWNUM` if it exists in your table) then try this query:

```
with CTE as 
(SELECT id,
        DateServiceStart,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as rn       
  FROM t )

UPDATE CTE 
 SET DateServiceStart
       =CAST('01/01/2014' as Datetime)+(rn-1)%5
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e5838/1)</kbd>

Comment: This is perfect, I've got it running and its so simple!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the `RowNum` column is sequential something like this would work

```
UPDATE yourTable SET DateServiceStart = DATEADD(day, (RowNum % 5), GETDATE())
```

If you you will need a cursor or while loop.

Answer (score 0):

my idea is big.so i am writing it here.
see it very easy.no need of loop

create row_number/rank/dense_rant whatever applicable in your update table column using **ntile(5)**
such that rownum is created like 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5 ........till the end.

now again create date range with rownum 1,2,3,4,5

join both to update.

show atleast 10 rows of original table and date range.so tht i write query .